# HDBSCAN dendrogram with Plotly, Python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, plotly-dash, hierarchical-clustering

Creating a dendrogram using `plotly.figure_factory.create_dendrogram` [has been discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452379/plotting-a-dendrogram-using-plotly-python).
I decided to use HDBSCAN as custering algorithm and would like to visualize the clusters with Plotly.

```
clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(
    algorithm ='best', 
    alpha = 1.0, 
    approx_min_span_tree = False,
    gen_min_span_tree = True,
    metric = 'hamming', 
    min_cluster_size = 2, 
    min_samples = 10,
    allow_single_cluster = True, 
    p = None)
clusters = clusterer.fit_predict(df_matrix)
```

How can I extract a dendrogram out of the code above?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

> clusterer.condensed_tree_.to_pandas()

to store the tree in a tree shaped manner within a pandas dataframe.
There are more methods available, also for visualizing.
See the docs: https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_hdbscan.html